# How to create an action which inserts a character via hotkey?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and sadly the API reference seems to be a bit lacking for the whole plugin system (aside from a few very useful tutorials on the JetBrains site.)  This plugin is for a custom language which associates to specific file types and the parser API is manageable along with the file associations and templating systems, but what I can't figure out seems like it should be a really easy issue to resolve in contrast to those.

I'd like to create a hotkey which when used in the editor (no menu items or toolbar icons, just a keyboard combination) which will insert a unicode character, or alternatively if there is an active selection, will wrap the selected text in a pair of unicode characters.

E.g. something to catch `ALT_SHIFT+[` in my file type and if there is no selection it would insert the character `⦓` in the current caret position, if there is a selection then it would wrap that selection in `⦓` ... `⦔`

This seems feasible since `.java` files actually use the `ALT+SHIFT+[` combination to change the selection in IntelliJ whereas my custom filetype currently just ignores it.

The custom file type inherits from `LanguageFileType` in the `com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes` package.

Edit:

Adding the code that resulted from this in case anyone else comes across this question:

**HotkeyAction** (needs to be registered in plugin.xml)

```
public class HotkeyAction extends AnAction {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getInstance("Aquae");
    private ArrayList<HotkeyHandler> hotkeyHandlers;

    public HotkeyAction() {
        super();
        this.hotkeyHandlers = new ArrayList<HotkeyHandler>();
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "{", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "}", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⧼", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⧽", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⦓", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⦔", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⦃", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⦄", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));

        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "(", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_9, SHIFT_MASK, false),
                ")", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_0, SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⦗", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_9, CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⦘", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_0, CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⦅", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_9, ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⦆", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_0, ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⸨", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_9, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⸩", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_0, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));

        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "[", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, 0, false),
                "]", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, 0, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⁅", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK, false),
                "⁆", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "【", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, ALT_MASK, false),
                "】", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, ALT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "〚", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_OPEN_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK, false),
                "〛", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK, false));

        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "<", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_COMMA, SHIFT_MASK, false),
                ">", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_PERIOD, SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "᚜", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_COMMA, CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "᚛", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_PERIOD, CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⦑", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_COMMA, ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⦒", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_PERIOD, ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
        this.AddBracketShortcut(true,
                "⟪", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_COMMA, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false),
                "⟫", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_PERIOD, CTRL_MASK | ALT_MASK | SHIFT_MASK, false));
    }

    HotkeyAction(ArrayList<HotkeyHandler> keyStrokes) {
        super();
        this.hotkeyHandlers = new ArrayList<HotkeyHandler>();
    }

    public void AddBracketShortcut(boolean completeWithoutSelection, String open, KeyStroke openKeyStroke, String close, KeyStroke closeKeyStroke) {
        HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler handler = new HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler(completeWithoutSelection, open, openKeyStroke, close, closeKeyStroke);
        this.hotkeyHandlers.add(handler);
        KeymapManager.getInstance().getActiveKeymap().addShortcut("org.aquae.slip.HotkeyAction", handler.getOpenShortcut());
        KeymapManager.getInstance().getActiveKeymap().addShortcut("org.aquae.slip.HotkeyAction", handler.getCloseShortcut());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent anActionEvent) {
        String s = "";
        InputEvent inputEvent = anActionEvent.getInputEvent();
        logger.warn(inputEvent.toString());
        boolean hit = false;
        Project project = anActionEvent.getProject();
        if (inputEvent instanceof KeyEvent) {
            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) inputEvent;
            int mask = 0;
            s = String.valueOf(keyEvent.getKeyChar());
            if (inputEvent.isShiftDown()) {
                s = "SHIFT" + (s.length() > 0 ? " + " + s : "");
                mask |= SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
            }
            if (inputEvent.isAltDown()) {
                s = "ALT" + (s.length() > 0 ? " + " + s : "");
                mask |= ALT_DOWN_MASK;
            }
            if (inputEvent.isControlDown()) {
                s = "CTRL" + (s.length() > 0 ? " + " + s : "");
                mask |= CTRL_DOWN_MASK;
            }
            logger.warn("KeyCode = " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
            logger.warn("Modifiers = " + keyEvent.getModifiers());
            logger.warn(s);
            for (HotkeyHandler hotkeyHandler : this.hotkeyHandlers) {
                if (hotkeyHandler.match(anActionEvent)) {
                    hit = true;
                    if (hotkeyHandler instanceof HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler) {
                        HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler hotkeyBracketInsertionHandler = (HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler) hotkeyHandler;
                        logger.warn(hotkeyBracketInsertionHandler.getOpen() + "x" + hotkeyBracketInsertionHandler.getClose());
                        WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(project, () -> { hotkeyHandler.execute(project, anActionEvent); });
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!hit) {
                logger.warn(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HotkeyHandler**

```
public abstract class HotkeyHandler {
    protected ArrayList<KeyStroke> _keyStrokes;
    protected ArrayList<Shortcut> _shortcuts;

    public HotkeyHandler(ArrayList<KeyStroke> keyStrokes) {
        this._keyStrokes = keyStrokes;
        this._shortcuts = new ArrayList<Shortcut>();
        for (KeyStroke keyStroke : keyStrokes) {
            this._shortcuts.add(new KeyboardShortcut(keyStroke, null));
        }
    }

    abstract void execute(Project project, AnActionEvent anActionEvent);

    public boolean indifferentMatch(int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        KeyStroke keyStroke = this._keyStrokes.get(i);
        if (keyStroke.getKeyCode() == keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
            int modifiers = keyEvent.getModifiers();
            if ((keyStroke.getModifiers() & (CTRL_MASK | CTRL_DOWN_MASK)) > 0) {
                if ((modifiers & (CTRL_MASK | CTRL_DOWN_MASK)) < 1) { return (false); }
                if ((modifiers & CTRL_MASK) > 0) { modifiers -= CTRL_MASK; }
                if ((modifiers & CTRL_DOWN_MASK) > 0) { modifiers -= CTRL_DOWN_MASK; }
            }
            if ((keyStroke.getModifiers() & (ALT_MASK | ALT_DOWN_MASK)) > 0) {
                if ((modifiers & (ALT_MASK | ALT_DOWN_MASK)) < 1) { return (false); }
                if ((modifiers & ALT_MASK) > 0) { modifiers -= ALT_MASK; }
                if ((modifiers & ALT_DOWN_MASK) > 0) { modifiers -= ALT_DOWN_MASK; }
            }
            if ((keyStroke.getModifiers() & (SHIFT_MASK | SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)) > 0) {
                if ((modifiers & (SHIFT_MASK | SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)) < 1) { return (false); }
                if ((modifiers & SHIFT_MASK) > 0) { modifiers -= SHIFT_MASK; }
                if ((modifiers & SHIFT_DOWN_MASK) > 0) { modifiers -= SHIFT_DOWN_MASK; }
            }
            if (modifiers < 1) { return (true); }
        }
        return (false);
    }
    public boolean match(AnActionEvent anActionEvent) {
        InputEvent inputEvent = anActionEvent.getInputEvent();
        if (!(inputEvent instanceof KeyEvent)) { return (false); }
        KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) inputEvent;
        for (int i = this._keyStrokes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (this.indifferentMatch(i, keyEvent)) { return (true); }
        }
        return (false);
    }

    public KeyStroke getKeyStroke(int i) { return (this._keyStrokes.get(i)); }
    public ArrayList<KeyStroke> getKeyStrokes() { return (this._keyStrokes); }
    public Shortcut getShortcut(int i) { return (this._shortcuts.get(i)); }
    public ArrayList<Shortcut> getShortcuts() { return (this._shortcuts); }
}
```

**HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler**

```
public class HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler extends HotkeyHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getInstance("Aquae");
    private boolean _completeWithoutSelection;
    private String _open;
    private String _close;

    public HotkeyBracketInsertionHandler(boolean completeWithoutSelection, String open, KeyStroke openKeyStroke, String close, KeyStroke closeKeyStroke) {
        super(new ArrayList<KeyStroke>() {{
            add(openKeyStroke);
            add(closeKeyStroke);
        }});
        this._completeWithoutSelection = completeWithoutSelection;
        this._open = open;
        this._close = close;
    }

    @Override
    void execute(Project project, AnActionEvent anActionEvent) {
        InputEvent inputEvent = anActionEvent.getInputEvent();
        if (!(inputEvent instanceof KeyEvent)) { return; }
        KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) inputEvent;
        FileEditorManager fileEditorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
        Editor textEditor = fileEditorManager.getSelectedTextEditor();
        final Document document = textEditor.getDocument();
        final CaretModel caretModel = textEditor.getCaretModel();
        final int caretOffset = caretModel.getOffset();
        if (caretOffset < 0) { return; }
        final SelectionModel selectionModel = textEditor.getSelectionModel();
        boolean rev = (caretOffset == selectionModel.getSelectionStart()) && (caretOffset != selectionModel.getSelectionEnd());
        boolean opening = this.indifferentMatch(0, keyEvent);
        if (opening) {
            if (this._completeWithoutSelection || selectionModel.hasSelection()) {
                document.insertString(selectionModel.getSelectionEnd(), this._close);
                document.insertString(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), this._open);
                caretModel.moveToOffset((rev ? selectionModel.getSelectionStart() : selectionModel.getSelectionEnd()) + (!selectionModel.hasSelection() ? this._open.length() : 0));
                selectionModel.setSelection(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), selectionModel.getSelectionEnd());
            } else {
                document.insertString(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), this._open);
                caretModel.moveToOffset(selectionModel.getSelectionEnd() + this._open.length());
            }
        } else {
            if (this._close.length() < 1) { return; }
            if (selectionModel.hasSelection()) {
                document.insertString(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), this._close);
                document.deleteString(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), selectionModel.getSelectionEnd());
                caretModel.moveToOffset(rev ? selectionModel.getSelectionStart() : selectionModel.getSelectionEnd());
                selectionModel.setSelection(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), selectionModel.getSelectionEnd());
            } else {
                document.insertString(selectionModel.getSelectionStart(), this._close);
                selectionModel.removeSelection();
                caretModel.moveToOffset(selectionModel.getSelectionEnd() + this._close.length());
            }
        }
    }

    public String getClose() { return (this._close); }
    public KeyStroke getCloseKeyStroke() { return (this._keyStrokes.get(1)); }
    public Shortcut getCloseShortcut() { return (this._shortcuts.get(1)); }
    public String getOpen() { return (this._open); }
    public KeyStroke getOpenKeyStroke() { return (this._keyStrokes.get(0)); }
    public Shortcut getOpenShortcut() { return (this._shortcuts.get(0)); }
}
```

**HotkeyPromoter** (needs to be registered in plugin.xml)

```
public class HotkeyPromoter implements ActionPromoter {
    @Override
    public List<AnAction> promote(List<AnAction> actions, DataContext dataContext) {
        AnAction action = ContainerUtil.findInstance(actions, HotkeyAction.class);
        return (action != null ? Collections.singletonList(action) : Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an 'action' which will perform corresponding changes - see [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/creating_an_action.html) for a start, and also [this section](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/action_system.html). 
As your action will operate in editor, it makes sense to use EditorAction as a base for your action class (then also you'll need to implement EditorActionHandler, which will perform actual logic).

Comment: Those were the unhelpful bits of documentation I referenced in relation to this issue.  Those describe how to get hotkeys in other areas (e.g. the file tree) but not how to use them in an editor of a specific file type.  I also tried the EditorAction already without luck (still just registers in the tool panel.)

Comment: To make your logic work only for a specific file type, you'll need to override 'isEnabledForCaret' method in your EditorActionHandler and make it return 'false' if editor is for unrelated file type.
If you don't need action to appear in any menu/toolbar, just don't use 'add-to-group' tag in action declaration.

Comment: My initial issue is that the action will only bind to the tool window for the project files, not the editor.  I can hit `ALT+SHIFT+[` there and get a popup message (my current debug method) but changing to the editor just doesn't do anything with the key combination.

Comment: The actual problem can be that another action is being triggered that is using the same shortcut. E.g. in my keymap I see 'Previous Emmet Edit Point' assigned to ALT+SHIFT+[ shortcut. You can try to assign a different shortcut to your action to confirm that (finding the unused one can be done by shortcut searching in keymap settings).
If you need your action to take preference over another action using the same shortcut, you can use ActionPromoter extension (see examples of its implementation in IDEA Community codebase).

Comment: I've poked at this a bit but can't get it to work.  Can you point me to a code sample doing similar?  Also, is it possible to have one action and handler to handle multiple shortcuts?  E.g. if you have a list of 20 of them, do you need an action and a handler for each?

Comment: My response wasn't accepted here, as it was too long for a comment. I'll respond in [your forum post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000604510-Catching-Multiple-Hotkeys-in-Editor-).

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this both here and on the JetBrains support forums.  I've accepted this as the correct answer and edited my question to include the code that resulted from this in case someone else searches for it.